# Como faço para que a checkbox tenha o valor da id do banco de dados correspondente ao registro que foi marcado?

Tags: php

```js
< script >
  function verificaChecks() {}
var aChk = document.getElementsByName("verifica");
for (var i = 0; i < aChk.length; i++) {
  if (aChk[i].checked == true) {
    if (aChk[i].value == "<?php echo $check?>") {
      <?php
            $status= mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE bloqueios SET  ESTADO = 'Desconsiderado' where id= $check");
  ?>
    }
  } else {
    <?php echo ("nenhum marcado"); ?>
    // CheckBox Não Marcado... Faça alguma outra coisa...
  }
}
} <
/script>
```

```html
<?php
 $dbname = mysqli_select_db($conn,"bloqueio-cartao") or die("Não foi possível selecionar o Banco");
 // Exibe o bloqueio e a multa
 $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM bloqueios  WHERE NOME LIKE '%".$nome."%' ");
 $numRegistros2=mysqli_num_rows($sql2);
 if ($numRegistros2 !=0) {
   echo '<tr>'."<td>";
 //echo ("<button id='r'>Recurso</button></td>");
 echo '<td>';
 echo ("<button> Desconsiderar</button>").'</td>';
 echo "<td>". ("<input type='button'  value='Desconsiderar' onclick='verificaChecks();'></td>");
 echo "<td>". ("<button> imprimir </button>")."</td>"."</tr>";
  while ($bloqueio = mysqli_fetch_object($sql2)) {
    $check= $bloqueio->id;
    echo '<tr>'."<td>";
     echo  ("<input type='checkbox' id='verifica' name='checkbox' value='<?php echo $check;?>'/>"); echo '
  <td>'; echo $bloqueio->HORA. '-' .$bloqueio->LINHA. '-' .$check.'</td>'.'</tr>'; echo '
  <td></td>'; } } // Se não houver registros else { echo "Nenhum bloqueio foi encontrado com esse nome ".$nome.""; } ?>
  </table>
  </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('btnSaveInDb').onclick = function(){
   
   let checkboxs = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox-class');
   
   let dataForm = [];
   
   for(let k = 0; k < checkboxs.length; k++){
       
       if(checkboxs[k].checked){
          
          dataForm.push({id:checkboxs[k].id, estado:'desconsiderado'});
          
       }
       
   }
   
   console.log(dataForm);
   
  $.post("demo_test_post.php",
  {
    data: {info:dataForm}
  },
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_id_1" class="checkbox-class"  />
Checkbox example 1 </label><br/>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_id_2" class="checkbox-class"  />
Checkbox example 2</label><br/>

<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_id_3" class="checkbox-class" />
</label>Checkbox example 3<br/>


<button id="btnSaveInDb">Salvar no Banco</button>
```

> Primeiro: Há um erro da `web semântica`, aqui:

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='verifica' name='checkbox' value='<?php echo $check;?>'/>
```

> Pois o id deve ser único.

O ideal seria fazer assim:

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='<?php echo $check; ?>' name='checkbox' value='<?php "1 ou 0";?>'/>
```

> Ou, de outra forma, assim:

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='<?php echo $check; ?>' data-id="<?php echo $check; ?>" name='checkbox' value='<?php echo $check;?>'/>
```

Aqui, usa-se o atributo global `data-*` .

Dessa forma, é possível fazer vários tipos de manipulações, principalmente, com javascript.

Comment: Obrigada, mas mesmo assim não resolveu meu problema =( Queria que ao marcar a checkbox, a mesma pegasse o id do registro correspondente e assim gravar um status pra esse registro como "desconsiderado" ....

Comment: Você quer fazer isso um por um? Por exemplo: clicar num checkbox e automaticamente já disparar algum evento e, em seguida, salvar alguma informação no banco, ou somente mostrar para o cliente?

Comment: salvar no banco

Comment: seleciono algumas checkboxs, automaticamente pega os ids. Depois aperto no botão desconsiderar e salvo "desconsiderado" no banco nesses ids que estão na check..

Comment: Vou editar aqui conforme entendi.

Comment: cada linha que contém a check obtém um id no banco, queria que a check obtivesse esse valor...

Comment: ok ja vejo... =)

Comment: Vi seu post, não quero gravar o id da check no banco. No banco tem as colunas: id , estudante, beneficio, cpf , utilização indevida, estado. Queria que a check pegasse esse id do banco pra eu poder adicionar na coluna estado "desconsiderado" ...

Comment: queria deixar assim:

Comment: id=1 estudante=bruna cpf=0000000 utilização= xxxxxx estado= desconsiderado

Comment: mas por enquanto o campos da coluna do estado estão em branco, preciso atualizar ali pegando o id

Comment: Tipo isto?
[
  {
    "id": "my_id_2",
    "estado": "desconsiderado"
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": "my_id_1",
    "estado": "desconsiderado"
  },
  {
    "id": "my_id_2",
    "estado": "desconsiderado"
  },
  {
    "id": "my_id_3",
    "estado": "desconsiderado"
  }
]

Comment: Sim, mas que eu não precise colocar o id na check manualmente entende? pq são muitas utilizações e a check está num loop... assim que gerasse a check na utilização pegasse o id do banco e nesse id gravasse desconsiderado...